# How do I vectorize this code that produces a scipy sparse matrix?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

Let me start off by explaining what I want to do. I am trying to build a recommendation system based off of `m` packages, each with `n` features, stored in an `m x n` sparse matrix `X`. To do this, I'm attempting to run kNN to get the `k` closest matches for a packages. I want to build an `m x m` sparse matrix `K` where `K[i, j]` is the dot product of rows `X[i]` and `X[j]` if `X[j]` was a package returned by kNN for `X[i]`, otherwise 0.

Here is the code I've written:

```
X = ...
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=self.n_neighbors, metric='l2')
knn.fit(X)
knn_indices = knn.kneighbors(X, return_distance=False)

m, k = X.shape[0], self.n_neighbors
K = lil_matrix((m, m))

for i, indices in enumerate(knn_indices):
    xi = X.getrow(i)
    for j in indices:
        xj = X.getrow(j)
        K[i, j] = xi.dot(xj.T)[0, 0]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make this more efficient. In my scenario, `m` is ~1.2 million, `n` is ~50000, and `k` is 500, so perf is very important.

The last part where I populate `K` is the bottleneck of my program. `getrow` seems to perform very poorly; according to the scipy docs, it makes a copy of the row, so `getrow` call could be copying up to 50k elements each time it's called. Also, in the innermost loop I can't figure out how to get back a scalar for `dot` instead of creating a whole new `1x1` sparse matrix.

How can I avoid these problems and speed up/vectorize the last part of this code? Thanks.

Comment: One thing that sparse matrices are good at is matrix multiplication, especially one sparse matrix with another. And the natural result of that is another sparse matrix.  So there's nothing wrong with having to use `[0,0]` to extract the scalar value from a (1,1) sparse matrix.

Comment: One thing that sparse matrices are not good at is iteration.  Row iteration returns a 1 row sparse matrix.  There are ways of streamlining that row extraction, getting the `indices` and `data` without making a full matrix.  But if you are going use that row in a `dot` product you will need the matrix.

Comment: Instead of doing every pair of `i` and `j` individually, could you do all or groups?  For example `X[i,:]` dot with `X[indices,:]`?  `csr` matrix indexing with a list is actually done with matrix multiplication - using an `extractor` sparse matrix.  You'll come out ahead if you can express the problem as several matrix multiplications using the whole matrices, rather than individual rows.

Comment: Scikit learn has some additional sparse utility functions, some coded in cython.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [21]: from scipy import sparse
In [22]: M = sparse.random(10,10,.2,'csr')
In [23]: M
Out[23]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Looking a `M.A`, I selected this small `knn_indices` array for testing:

```
In [45]: knn = np.array([[4],[2],[],[1,3]])
```

Your double loop:

```
In [46]: for i, indices in enumerate(knn):
    ...:     xi = M[i,:]
    ...:     for j in indices:
    ...:         xj = M[j,:]
    ...:         print((xi*xj.T).A)
    ...:         
[[0.35494592]]
[[0.]]
[[0.08112133]]
[[0.56905781]]
```

The inner loop can be condensed:

```
In [47]: for i, indices in enumerate(knn):
    ...:     xi = M[i,:]
    ...:     xj = M[indices,:]
    ...:     print((xi*xj.T).A)
    ...:         
[[0.35494592]]
[[0.]]
[]
[[0.08112133 0.56905781]]
```

and with the assignment:

```
In [49]: k = sparse.lil_matrix((4,5))
In [50]: for i, indices in enumerate(knn):
    ...:     xi = M[i,:]
    ...:     for j in indices:
    ...:         xj = M[j,:]
    ...:         k[i,j] = (xi*xj.T)[0,0]
    ...:         
    ...:         
In [51]: k.A
Out[51]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.35494592],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.08112133, 0.        , 0.56905781, 0.        ]])
```

The second loop with

```
 k[i,indices] = (xi*xj.T)
```

does the same thing.

It may be possible to do something with the `i` loop as well, but this is at least a start.

That `knn` doesn't need to an array.  With differing inner list lengths it's an object dtype anyways.  Better leave it as list.

An alternative to filling this `lil` matrix, would be to accumulate `i`, `indices` and the dot product in `coo` style arrays.

```
In [64]: r,c,d = [],[],[]
In [65]: for i, indices in enumerate(knn):
    ...:     xi = M[i,:]
    ...:     xj = M[indices,:]
    ...:     t = (xi*xj.T).data
    ...:     if len(t)>0:
    ...:         r.extend([i]*len(indices))
    ...:         c.extend(indices)
    ...:         d.extend(t)
    ...:         
In [66]: r,c,d
Out[66]: 
([0, 3, 3],
 [4, 1, 3],
 [0.3549459176547072, 0.08112132851228658, 0.5690578146292733])
In [67]: sparse.coo_matrix((d,(r,c))).A
Out[67]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.35494592],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.08112133, 0.        , 0.56905781, 0.        ]])
```

In my test case the 2nd row doesn't have any nonzero values, requiring an extra test in the loop.  I don't know if this is any faster than the `lil` approach.